# Cannot boot kali linux after dist-upgrade, stucks at 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, initramfs, initrd

I did a dist-upgrade from 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 to 4.4.0-kali1-amd64 but when I restart, the screen stucks at 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'. 
I had to use the advanced boot options to boot using 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 to be able to boot instead.
What can I do to fix the problem?

I am running kali linux on dual boot with windows 7. Kali is running on an encrypted LVM.

Comment: I installed the Kali on dual boot with Windows 8, and after upgrade, the 4.4.0-kali1-amd64 ramdisk doesn't work (but 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 ramdisk works fine). This is the bug tracker https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3098